# Publish or manage permissions are not permited to to be requested with read permissions FACEBOOK SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am currently trying to implement Facebook Login and Registration Flow to our Application.
But there is a little Problem. I've got the permissions from our Web-Api and if i try to pass them to the `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions` Method of the Facebook SDK an error with the following message occurs :

```
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'com.facebook.sdk:InvalidOperationException', reason: 'FBSession:
> Publish or manage permissions are not permited to to be requested with
> read permissions.
```

So it seems that i cant pass publish or manage permissions with this method.
My question now is : Why can i not pass this parameter to the openActiveSession and how should i do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to open an active session with permissions other than `ReadPermissions`, you can try

```
 openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions 
                         defaultAudience:(FBSessionDefaultAudience) 
                            allowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
                       completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error)handler
```

method. Or if you want to reauthorize an already open session with other permissions , you can use

```
- (void)reauthorizeWithReadPermissions:(NSArray*)readPermissions
                 completionHandler:(FBSessionReauthorizeResultHandler)handler;
```

or

```
 - (void)reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:(NSArray*)writePermissions
                    defaultAudience:(FBSessionDefaultAudience)defaultAudience
                  completionHandler:(FBSessionReauthorizeResultHandler)handler;
```

Methods. Try going through FBSession.h class.

Comment: So if i want to open active session with read and publish permissions  i have to call one of the openActiveSession Methods and then reauthorize it ?

Comment: If you have an active session, you can reauthorize it with `read` or `publish_action` permissions. If you are opening a active session,its recommended to open it with read permissions. Thereafter, you can reauthorize it with other permissions.

Comment: Refer this link for Upgrading from 3.1 to 3.2   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.1-to-3.2/

Comment: these methods are now deprecated. Do you have some other to replace them

Comment: Sorry I haven't looked into the Facebook SDK since this answer. You'll have to look into their SDK documentations, they must have signaled to the suggested methods in place of the deprecated ones.