# forge.facebook.authorize(["create_event"] => FBSession: Publish or manage permissions are not permited

Tags: facebook-graph-api, trigger.io

Only when asking for this specific permission:

```
forge.facebook.authorize(["create_event"], function (auth) {

}, function(error) {
    forge.logging.info(error);
});
```

I get:

```
[INFO] { message: 'FBSession: Publish or manage permissions are not permited to to be requested with read permissions.',
[INFO]   type: 'UNEXPECTED_FAILURE' }
```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Also just realized that now since the permissions were granted on Android, the iOS app breezes through since FB doesnt seem to care which device is leveraging the perms. The issue seems to be in the forge iOS native code that requests "non-read" permissions. Could a trigger-io engineer look into that?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure something is wrong with your permission settings.

Creating an event is an [extended permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/). Your client apparently does not have the right to do so.
You only have read permissions.

You should be able to change that online by requesting for the additional permissions you need.

Comment: I actually just tried that same code on android and it requests the corrects permissions on there, so it seems to be that it could be related to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933955/publish-or-manage-permissions-are-not-permited-to-to-be-requested-with-read-perm

Comment: As in the forge bindings to the iOS facebook SDK.

Comment: Did the solution provided in that link help you at all?

Comment: Well it's about the native code that triggerio is supplementing, I don't have access to that source.