# FBSDKGraphRequest in React Native returning incomplete object

Tags: ios, react-native, fbsdk

So I have implemented the react native FBSDKGraphRequest and login button.  Login is working correctly, but when i attempt a graph request of the user, instead of the complete object i expect the /me endpoint to return

`{
   "id": "162036280799349",
   "birthday": "08/08/1980",
   "email": "test_ppjeffg_eight\u0040tfbnw.net",
   "first_name": "Test",
   "gender": "male",
   "last_name": "Eight",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/162036280799349/",
   "locale": "en_US",
   "name": "Test Eight",
   "timezone": -8,
   "updated_time": "2015-07-28T18:22:16+0000",
   "verified": false
}`

I just get

`Object {name: "Test Eight", id: "162036280799349"}`

I very well may be doing the request incorrectly, though I've done everything according to documentation.  Here is the relevant source code:

```
class LoadingOverlay extends BaseComponent{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this._bind(/*'_fetchFriendsRequestFunction'*/);
        this.state = {isVisible: true,
                  token: null,
                  profileInfo: null}


    }

  _fetchGraphRequestFunction(){
    console.log("start");
    var fetchProfileRequest = new FBSDKGraphRequest((error, result) => {
  if (error) {
    alert('Error making request.');
  } else {
    // Data from request is in result
    console.log(result);
  }
}, '/me');
// Start the graph request.
fetchProfileRequest.start();

  }

    render(){
        return(
            <Overlay isVisible={this.state.isVisible}>
            <BlurView style={styles.background} blurType="dark">
            <FBSDKLoginButton
                onLoginFinished={(error,result)=>{
                    if (error){
                        alert('Error Logging In.');
                    } else {
                        if (result.isCanceled){
                            alert('Login Cancelled.');
                        } else {
                            FBSDKAccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken((token)=>{
                                console.log(token.tokenString);
                this._fetchGraphRequestFunction();
                            })


                        }
                    }
                }}
                onLogoutFinished={()=>console.log('Logged Out.')}
                readPermissions={['public_profile', 'email', 'user_birthday', 'user_friends']}
                publishPermissions={['publish_actions']}/>
            </BlurView>

      </Overlay>
        );
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request additional parameters from Facebook by either appending them to the uri like this:

```
/me?fields=id,name,email
```

or by calling the addStringParameter function on the FBSDKGraphRequest object like this:

```
fetchProfileRequest.addStringParameter('picture,email,gender','fields');
```

However, what fields you get in return depends on the permission of your app and the settings of the user.

Also, note this little trick from the ios FB sdk documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginButton/

> Note, that if read permissions are specified, then publish permissions should not be specified.

So try sending an empty publishPermissions parameter and see if that fixed it.

More information here: 
[Publish or manage permissions are not permited to to be requested with read permissions FACEBOOK SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933955/publish-or-manage-permissions-are-not-permited-to-to-be-requested-with-read-perm)

https://coderwall.com/p/gkeqcq/request-read-and-publish-permissions-simultaneously-using-ios-facebook-support

I'd love to see an example of the flow to make this work in react native if anyone has it.